# Avoid Duplication of ReCAPTCHA V3 html code in ASP.Net Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha-v3

I am working on an ASP.Net project where I have to add Recaptcha V3 support to multiple forms. For the frontend changes, I have added the following HTML code as mentioned in Recaptcha docs -

1.)Button Submit

```
 <button type="button"
  class="btn btn-success pull-right g-recaptcha"
  data-sitekey=" My ReCaptcha Key"
  data-callback='onSubmit'
  data-action=' My Action Name'>
  Form Submit
 </button>
```

2.)Callback function

```
<script>
function onSubmit(token) {
    if(!verify()) { return false; }
    document.getElementById(" My Form Name").submit();
}
</script>
```

Now, the concern is raised that these changes for multiple forms will cause lots of duplication. The following concerns are raised  -

- It also duplicates any defects into multiple places
- It increases the difficulty of adding new instances/changing to an
  alternative service/disabling this feature
- It makes the various instances of the copy/pasted code more difficult
  to find, especially as they are modified

My thoughts -

Regarding Button Submit Code -

Since the Button tag is needed I assume we can avoid duplication of the "Recaptcha Key". I am thinking instead of hardcoding the captcha key in every HTML form, I can make it part of the form model and pass it every time the form is loaded.

Is it the correct solution to the problem of my code as well as the captcha key duplication? Is there any other way that will address the raised concerns?

Regarding the Callback function -

I am thinking I can keep all form names the same and .js include the relevant code.

Will my above solutions mitigate the raised concerns? Is there any other better approach to this problem?

Comment: Put the code in a Partial. That way its only in one place, then you just have to add your partial to all your forms. Maybe name your partial `RecaptchaSubmit` so its discoverable.

Comment: Normally you should put the captcha on login page on the top of hierarchically biggest element .

Comment: @mxmissile Forms are present in different projects in the same solution, So it's not possible to use partials here.

Comment: @firatt_ Captcha is beings added to all public-facing non-authenticated forms.